# Drupal-possible settings.php error

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have uploaded drupal on a remote server, and the created a database,user there. Then when I run install script on server. I get this error :

```
Failed to connect to your database server. The server reports the following message: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'a3706350_pasek1'@'localhost' (using password: YES).
```

I simply created a new php file and named it settings.php and copied all the contents  of default.settings.php to settings.php.

I tried writing this part on my own and then running the script and I got another error.

```
    $databases = array (
  'default' => array(
    'default' => array (
      'database' => 'name of database uploaded on remote server',
      'username' => 'root',
      'password' => 'root',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
);
```

I already had it when I run the install.php on my localhost. Can you tell me what I should do? I googled the error but I couldn't find a solution. I also changed settings.php's permissions to 666 before running install.php.
Thanks.

Comment: try installing a fresh site on the host and see if it supports it. After that copy everything in your local sites folder to the sites folder on server "EXCEPT settings.php". Change permission of settings.php and do the changes you did above ( point to correct db). See if it works. If it work and you are not able to login ( due to password incorrect. Then copy the salt from old settings.php on local to the one on server and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

The mysql database doesn't recognise the login a3706350_pasek1. Maybe you need to create it first. Otherwise it's because the password is wrong.

Comment: Thanks but I already created it before installation. And password is also correct I think. I use a free webserver (000webhost.com) may it be because of that?

Comment: Try writing a very small php script that just connects to mysql and prints the results. In other words, take Drupal out of the equation until you know that the database is accessible.